# JavaScript code not select items in Codigniter view

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a view in codeigniter project that used to select items from a MySQL table. Table includes the following data (As Example).

```
+---------+------------------------+------+--------+
| item_id |       item_name        | uom  | is_qty |
+---------+------------------------+------+--------+
|       1 | Light Palaser LED 50W  | unit |      2 |
|       2 | Light Palaser LED 100W | unit |      4 |
|       3 | Light Palaser LED 150W | unit |      6 |
+---------+------------------------+------+--------+
```

Then I want to select that data using the following view :
[image]

So, I used the followng code fragment to do that.

```
$(document).on('select2:select', '#equipment', function () {
        var equipment = $('#equipment').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url('repair/getEquipmentDetails')?>",
            data: {token: equipment},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.results != null) {
                    var jData = data.results[0];
                    var row_no = (new Date).getTime(), item_id = jData.item_id, item_name = jData.item_name, item_bqty = jData.is_qty, item_unit = jData.uom, item_cat = jData.name;
                    var newTr = $('<tr id="row_' + row_no + '" class="row_' + item_id + '" data-item-id="' + item_id + '"></tr>');
                    var tr_html = '<td><input name="item_name[]" type="hidden" class="item_name" value="' + item_name + '"><input name="item_name[]" type="hidden" class="item_name" value="' + item_name + '">' + '<span class="sname" id="item_name_' + row_no + '">' + item_name + ' </span></td>';
                    tr_html += '<td class="text-center">' + '<input name="uom[]" type="hidden" value="' + item_unit + '">' + '<span class="text-right scost" id="uom_' + row_no + '">' + item_unit + '</span></td>';
                    tr_html += '<td><input name="quantity_balance[]" type="hidden" class="rbqty" value="' + formatNumber(-1* item_bqty, 0) + '"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" readonly name="quantity[]" type="text" value="' + formatNumber(item_bqty, 0) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="quantity_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"></td>';
                    tr_html += '<td class="rec_con"><input class="form-control text-center repairQTY" name="repairQTY[]" type="number" step="any" value="" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="repairQTY_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"></td>';
                    tr_html += '<td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times tip redel" id="' + row_no + '" title="Remove" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></td>';
                    newTr.html(tr_html);
                    newTr.prependTo("#reTable");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The url `url: "<?=site_url('repair/getEquipmentDetails')?>"`  is working fine and retured relevant data correctly. But my view selected same items for any select. If I select different items at a time, the list outs same result as follows :

[image]

I can't find the in-correct point. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: use `console.dir(data);` instead of `console.log(data);` to debug your ajax success, since you expecting an array back. Check what you get...

Comment: @ Vickel. Got the same result. No change.

Comment: so you are not getting an array back and the if clause is not executed?

Answer (score 0):

var equipment = $('#equipment').val();
put console log for equipment and check whether you get correct equipmentid.